# List of Environment Variables to Dictionary with Values - Idiomatic F#

Tags: .net, dictionary, f#, environment-variables

What is the idiomatic way to take a F# list of string like

```
let myList = ["BUILD_NUMBER"; "GIT_COMMIT"; "GIT_BRANCH"]
```

and convert that to a Dictionary where the words above are the keys and the corresponding Environment Variable is the value.

Should  all that be done in a one-liner or piped expression? I am missing the FP background to know how to go from list to Dictionary. What is the most idiomatic way to do this in F#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [dict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx) function should do the work :

```
let env =
  myList
  |> Seq.map (fun var -> var, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable var)
  |> dict
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to @Sehnsucht's answer:

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() already returns a dictionary, so if you don't want to restrict yourself to the names you specified you could just say:

```
let d = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()
printfn "%s" d.["BUILD_NUMBER"]
```

If you only ever access d.[xxxx] in your code (where xxxx is one of the strings you specify in your question), there's arguably no reason to make another dictionary just for those names.